# Hide certain elements of nested list based on class

Tags: jquery

Given the following sample nested list:

```html
<ul id="toplist">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <ul>
        <li class="active">Item 1a</li>
        <li>Item 1b</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 2a</li>
        <li>Item 2b</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 3a</li>
        <li>Item 3b</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to hide every top-level `li` that doesn't have a child with class `active`. So in the above instance, *Item 2* and its children should be hidden, as well as *Item 3* and its children. *Item 1* and its children should remain.

I have tried something like:

```
$("#toplist").not(".active").hide();
```

But this was wiping out everything.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Where is your jQuery code?

Comment: Apologies, I was trying to do something like $("#toplist").not(".active").hide(); but that was wiping out everything. Sorry, wasn't aware of the requirement to post the jquery. Wasn't trying to offend anyone, just trying to save myself from embarrassment.  Obviously failed at both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you correct your invalid HTML (you can't have a `<ul>` as a child of another `<ul>`, only a `<li>`), this works:

```js
$('#toplist > li').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).find('li.active').length) $(this).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="toplist">
    <li>Item 1
        <ul>
            <li class="active">Item 1a</li>
            <li>Item 1b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2a</li>
            <li>Item 2b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3
        <ul>
            <li>Item 3a</li>
            <li>Item 3b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Wrote the list html quick, didn't notice the error, thanks.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain the problem with the answer?

Comment: `$('#toplist > li:not(:has(".active"))').hide()` should work with corrected HTML. It is much shorter and is quite readable.

Comment: @Regent - So post it as your own answer.

Comment: @j08691 nope, it doesn't make sense, because it has already been in another answer. What I really suggest is to add alternative version to your answer. Or at least it will be in comments.